# Getting a list of commits along with the commit message and hash in Git

Tags: git

I have a project in Git. What I want is a list of only the commit messages and the hashes between two commits and store it in a text file. Is there any command that does this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
git log --pretty=oneline commit1...commit2 > file
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but gets the entire log for all the commits right from the initial import.

Comment: Forgot the ellipsis. It's fixed now. Give it a shot.

Comment: To anyone else who was wondering, the ellipsis is syntactically important. It's not just shorthand added by @NoufalIbrahim to imply multiple arguments. Removing the ellipsis makes a completely different query.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim : How to get all commits ?

Comment: Drop the range selection part.

Comment: You can also limit the output with a time range, for example to list the commits since 2 days ago you can add --since=2.days - more info here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History#limit_options

Comment: For anyone looking: `git log --pretty=oneline` will print all commits to the terminal.