# How do I list commit messages between certain commits?

Tags: linux, git, logging

Is it possible to use git diff to show only the  commit log messages? Maybe git diff is not the right tool to use it but basically I want to see the commit messages between certain commits, and I definetely do not want to count lines to see what I want to see. I know there is git log which can show certain lines but that is not what I want. I am trying to compare Blender commits, so there are alot of stuff going on and I definetely do not want to go up and down and cut and paste logs to see what i ned.

thanks

Comment: `git log` can do that - what about it do you not want ?

Comment: Can you tell me how git log can show me only the commit messages of  "git diff 88e6980 3f59bdc1bd0"  (which is like 1725138 lines) from the Blender code base?

Comment: `git log 88e6980^..3f59bdc1bd0`  , with the first hash being the oldest

Comment: `git log --format='%s' 88e6980..3f59bdc1bd0`?

Comment: @alfunx feel free to add it as a reply, I accept your reply as the solution. It seems to work based on my testing here

Comment: `git log --oneline 88e6980~..3f59bdc1bd0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a list of commits along with the commit message and hash in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703238/getting-a-list-of-commits-along-with-the-commit-message-and-hash-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+commit+messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list just the commit messages (without *any* other information) between two commits, you can use

```
git log --format='%s' <old-commit>..<new-commit>
```

Note that `<old-commit>` won't be included - use e.g. `<old-commit>~..<new-commit>` to have it included.